# Get attribute value from 'has_many through' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models:  `user` ,  `post`  and `comment` .

Each `user` can post one `comment` to one `post`.

Each `post` have many `comment` s.

My question is:

How can I get the value of the post's `comment` of the `current_user`?

```
# model/user.rb
has_many :comments
has_many :posts through :comments

# model/post.rb
has_many :comments

# model/comment.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

I know I can do it with:

```
# in the controller
@comments = current_user.comments
@user_post_comment = @comments.where(:post_id => post_id).first
```

First, I think it must be some better way to do it.

Second, beacause there are maybe some posts in one page, so I must do something likes `@posts.each do |post|` to display the posts in the view.

**Updated**

> And then do like `current_user.post.comment`.
>
> That's I want to know how to do it.

Any help would be great, thanks all!

**Updated 2**

I hope this code below can help you understand what I want to do.

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.name %>
  <%= how to show current_user comment of the post %>
<% end %>
```

**Solution**

And now I have a solution like this:

```
# controller：

@comments_by_curr_user = Comment.
  where(post_id: @post.ids). # if paginate
  where(user_id: current_user.id).
  group_by(&:post_id)


# view：

<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.name %>
  <% @comments_by_curr_user[post.id].each do |comment| %>
      ... .............
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I think you have wrong association

Comment: @Vishal Could you show me?

Comment: You have a few typos in your question. It should be `has_many :posts, through :comments`; `has_many :comments`. You should fix that in your question's description.

Comment: @etagwerker Thank you, updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `post_id`, then

```
current_user.comments.find_by(post_id: post_id)
```

Returns a single comment made by `current_user` to that post.

As to your second update, you could make a helper method in the post model that looks maybe something like this

```
# app/models/post.rb
def find_comment_for_user(user)
  user.comments.find_by(post_id: self.id)
end
```

Now simply use this method in your view

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.name %>
  <%= post.find_comment_for_user(current_user) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you, it looks working. But I have question about how to use it in the view? `current_user.comments.find_by(post_id: post_id)` should write in the controller ? @Coolness

Comment: @floox, yeah you should use this in the controller method that renders your view, store the result in an instance variable, e.g `@comment` and use that variable in the view.

Comment: @Collness,  I know it can done in the controller: `@comment = current_user.comments.find_by(post_id: post_id)` . Now the question is : How can I get the special `post_id` in the controller that render the view, I can only get the `@posts` that will be use `@posts.each do |post|` in the controller.

Comment: That is to say, In the controller, I can just get the `@posts` , and then when `@posts` render in the view, I can get the `@post.id`. How to solve this? Thank you. @Coolnees .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@comments = current_user.posts.where(id: post_id).first.comments
```

And I think you model relationship should be

```
# model/user.rb
has_many posts
has_many :comments

# model/post.rb
has_many comments

# model/comment.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why the comment model didn't need the `belongs_to :user` ?

Comment: @floox sorry for my missunderstanding, answer is edited.

Comment: Maybe I don't need the `@comments` , because I must first do the loop of the `@posts.each do |post|` , and then do like `current_user.post.comment`.

Comment: What you exactly want, can you please update your question?